# Replace parent view router view with children in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a routing configuration as given in the code snippet below -

```
export const projectRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'projects', component: ProjectComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'project/:id', component: ProjectDetailsComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path : 'adduser', component: AddMemberComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is the module definition (this is not root module btw, this is a sub / feature module) -

```
//imports are removed to maintain sanity

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProjectRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [routableComponents],
  providers: [ProjectService]
})
export class ProjectModule { }
```

And the project details HTML is -

```
<div *ngIf="project" class="row justify-content-md-center">
   <!-- project details here -->
</div>
<router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

Now I want to show add-user form when user goes to this route - 
`/project/{id}/adduser`.

Since route `adduser` is children of `project/:id`, it is loading in `router-outlet` under that HTML. However, I want to replace the same view and not show it under already rendered HTML. Like given in the picture blow -

[image: Existing setup]

**What I want to achieve -**

[image]

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: update your post with module definition code.

Comment: @Aravind - added it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider removing adduser from the child status:

```
export const projectRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'projects', component: ProjectComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'project/:id', component: ProjectDetailsComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuard]},

      { path : 'projects/:id/adduser', component: AddMemberComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}

  }
]
```

Comment: Sure, can do that but is that the right way to achieve it?

Comment: AFAIK, yes. I cannot see any hacking here.

Comment: and how can I navigate user to this route through HTML?

Answer (score 0):

ProjectDetailsComponent template must contain the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` so that children can be rendered there.

Comment: what if I want to replace the content from parent `<router-outlet>` only?

Comment: then there must be route in router config at root level mapped to what you want to render ...when you click addMember button ....you can navigate in code to that route. Also there is a concept of named router outlet(secondary routes) which you can try to implement.